# FORFILES path returning invalid directory name on valid directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm attempting to iterate over files using `FORFILES` in the Windows 8 command window using the following:

```
CD "%RODIR%"
FORFILES /P "./DarkestHour" /C "cmd /c echo @fname"
```

Where `RODIR` is a user variable defined like so:

```
SET RODIR
RODIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\RedOrchestra
```

The `RedOrchestra` folder contains a folder called `DarkestHour`, however, I get this error message from `FORFILES`:

> ERROR: The directory name is invalid.

Even attempting to do this (no relative pathing), yields the same error:

```
FORFILES /P "%RODIR%/DarkestHour" /C "cmd /c echo @fname"
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Is there some sort of restriction on `FORFILES`' `/P` command?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: i belive its because spaces inside of `%RODIR%`. Try `set "RODIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\RedOrchestra"`

Comment: The issue is not the `RODIR` definition, as i can `cd` into it via `cd "%RODIR%"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` is a **switch** indicator. `\` is a **directory delimiter**.

Here's a demo which suits my system:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
forfiles /p "./one" /c "cmd /c echo @fname"
ECHO ===================
forfiles /p ".\one" /c "cmd /c echo @fname"

POPD
GOTO :EOF
```